Szemerédi-Trotter theorem for planes and lines
The Szemerédi-Trotter theorem states:
Theorem Let $P$ be a set of $m$ lines in $\mathbb R^2$ and let $L$ be a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb R^2$. Then
$$\#\{(p,\ell)\in P\times L:p\in\ell\}\lesssim (mn)^{2/3}+m+n.$$
Is there a similar statement for sets of lines and planes in $\mathbb R^3$? In other words, given a set of lines $L$ of size $m$ and a set of planes $H$ of size $n$ in $\mathbb R^3$, what is the best bound for
$$\#\{(\ell,h)\in L\times H:\ell\subset h\}?$$
More generally, what can be said in $\mathbb R^d$ about the incidence set between a set $H_i$ of $i$-dimensional hyperplanes and a set $H_{i-1}$ of $(i-1)$-dimensional hyperplanes?

The very same bound holds. This is because if you intersect your configuration with a generic plane, then you get a point-line configuration with the same incidences. On the other hand, of course, any point-line configuration can be lifted into the space by taking the direct product with a line perpendicular to the plane. The question becomes more interesting if you go to higher dimensions, see for example
Cheng - Line-Plane Incidence Bound in $\mathbb R^4$.

Thank you for the answer! The same argument shows the answer to my more general question only depends on the codimension $d-i$.
